# Phonegap unique id for each device(Permission for limited devices)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

In my app developed by Phonegap, there is requirement below.
1. Only limited devices are able to use our app. Every device needs to get register key from the back-end before using app.
2. When a user want to log in with the specific account in another device and he has gotten a new register key, the key of the previous device will be disabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Starting wirth iOS7 it is not longer possible to identify devices. `UUID` and mac address based identifier are no longer available. You will need to to build some thing you self.

Comment: you want to know how to create a unique id..? right?

Comment: @rckoenes Yes. Actually, I need to get a mark to identify each device. Do you have any idea for 'build some thing' to identify devices?

Comment: @mvp actually,I want to get a method to know 'these 2 are different devices'.

Comment: @JackHe that is no longer possible on iOS 7, you can only generate a random string/number and save it on the device. There is no other option.

Comment: @rckoenes Could we generate a guid for a device only when it is installed and Also delete it when app is uninstalled? Is that possible?

Comment: @JackHe Yes you can generate one on first start of the device, but no you will not be able to delete it when your app is uninstalled.

Comment: @rckoenes Really thanks for your patience.Could you direct me the solution for 'generate one on first start of the device'?